# How to enumerate all the places where there are identical ways of choosing concatenated numbers from the concatenated X,Y, and Z?

Tags: combinatorics

How to enumerate all the places where there are identical ways of choosing concatenated numbers?

> $X, Y$ and $Z$ are friends. $X$ comes up with an integer between 1 and $10, Y$ comes up with an integer between 1 and 50 , and $Z$ comes up with an integer between 1 and 100 . The three numbers are then concatenated (combined) to form a larger number $t$ in the order of the numbers chosen by first $X$, then $Y$, and finally $Z$.
> For example, if $X$ chose $4, Y$ chose 39 , and $Z$ chose $67, t$ would be 43,967 .

Naively, you would think there are 50,000 choices but there are actually 46320 because of the example below.

How do you find all the 3680 identical concatenated numbers?

For example, There are two ways of obtaining the number 7345, Either the first person chooses 7 and the second person chooses three and the last chooses 45 or the first chooses 7, the second chooses 34, and the last person chooses five.

Comment: Well, the example provides a roadmap, right?  The first digit is $X's$ number, so we can forget that.  Then $Y$ either chose the next digit or the next two, so you have to count those cases.

Comment: Maybe you should check your 46320. I find 46760 ; 729 with lenth 3, 7776 with length 4, 34146 with length 5, 4068 with length 6 and 41 with length 7.